# Pandas - Multiline plot

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data frame is composed by 3 elements: Name, Date and Weight.

I would like to plot a line graph where the X axis is the date, the Y is the COUNT OF weights (how many times a give subject weighted himself throughout the day) and each line is a different name.

In order to do that, i gave it a shot:

```
dtFrame.sort_values(['date'])

dtFrame.groupby(by=["date","name"])
dtFrame.plot.line()
plt.show()
```

but that was not what I expected... basically what i want is: `Select name, date, count(1) FROM myTable Groupby name, date`

What am i doing wrong?

Edit1: Sample csv data

day, name, weight
1,a,5
1,a,5
1,a,7
1,b,5
1,b,5
2,a,5
2,a,5
2,a,7
2,b,5
2,b,5
3,a,5
3,a,5
3,a,7
3,b,5
3,b,5
4,a,5
4,a,5
4,a,7
4,b,5
4,b,5

Comment: Any chance you can add some sample data?

Comment: @rafaelc i created some! tks for the interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = df.groupby(['name','day']).count().unstack().T
res.index = res.index.droplevel()
res.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way is to just loop through the names and plot each individually

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 18))

for name, group in data.groupby('name'):
    group.date.value_counts().plot(ax=ax, label=name)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: will this give me N plots or a single plot with N lines? I really need just a single image...

Comment: @Leonardo - by passing the parameter `ax` to `plot()` they will all be on the same chart

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like that

```
df.groupby(['day', 'name']).weight.count().unstack().plot()
```

[image: The resulting plot]